# What does the transparent repository icon mean in Azure DevOps?

Tags: git, user-interface, azure-devops, icons, repository

There are two kinds of the icon. Orange and transparent.

Orange is a normal repository as I understand, but what does the other one mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fork of another repository.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/forks?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio